# skipLocationChange is not working in angular5

Tags: angular

I wrote this in my html

```
<a class="text-danger" [routerLink]="['/articles-view', {'articleid': article.articleId, 'user_id':user._id}]" (click)="article()">
```

I tried this

```
<a class="text-danger" [routerLink]="['/articles-view', {'articleid': article.articleId, 'user_id':user._id}]" (click)="article()" skipLocationChange>
```

I am getting like this in my url

```
localhost:4200/articles-view;articleid=WMCA249900 user_id=5c1a37993b4c782788a552b2
```

I dont want to get id's in my url. Can someone please help.

Comment: You can try like this                                                                                        
[routerLink]="['/articles-view', {'articleid': article.articleId, 'user_id':user._id, 'skipLocationChange': true } ]"

Comment: I am getting like this in url------------> localhost:4200/articles-view;articleid=WMCA249900 user_id=5c1a37993b4c782788a552b2 skipLocationChange': true